# SMTP Client won't accept umlauts in password

Tags: c#, .net, credentials, system.net.mail

I wrote a smal programm for a client which sends Mails over an outlook server. To identify yourself you have to type in your username (mail-address) and your password.
The problem is, that one of the users has an umlaut (ä, ö, ü) in his password and therefore it dosn't work form him. I tested this scenario with my own password and yes, the one with the umlaut didn't work.

So, I use System.Net.Mail with this lines:

```
var mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
mailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "passwordWithUmlaut");
mailClient.Send(Email);
```

As said before, when the password has no umlaut it works perfectly fine but with the umlaut it dosn't accept the mail.

The Error which is thrown, states out that a "secure connection is needed" but ssl is activated. Furthermore it says, that "the client could not be authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. [PR0P264CA0263.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"

Does anyone knows how to make it work with umlauts, or is this a common problem I have to live with.

Comment: What do the office365 docs say? If they do not allow for umlauts, then they don't. Nothing on your part you can do. If they do allow them, it _may_ be some client options/settings. Maybe a string encoding issue.

Comment: Also: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/authentication-fails-when-you-use-an-imap-server-in-outlook-2016-16273eaf-ec20-83f0-f25c-4277c722d42f

Comment: Ah well, ok thanks for the article this may helps me already

Comment: As a workaround you can switch to google mail.